# Web Audio does not work on some devices (Panner Audio)

Tags: audio, web-audio-api

I am trying to add all my page sounds to web audio panner such that the sounds move from left to right. For this I created this function to add all of them to pannner but it seems to work only on some devices and on other devices no sound comes from audio even when it is showing the speaker icon in tab( audio is playing).

```
let panNode;    var source=new Array(60);
const myAudio = document.querySelectorAll('audio');
const panControl = document.querySelector('.panning-control');
 var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;   
const audioCtx = new AudioContext();
  panNode = audioCtx.createStereoPanner();


for(let i = 0; i<myAudio.length; i++){
  source[i] = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(myAudio[i]);
   
  source[i].connect(panNode);
  panNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
}
```

Ignore how I manage to move audio as I have created a separate function to automatically increase or decrease pannode value every second. I need help in adding all sounds to pannode compatible with all devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `createStereoPanner()` isn't available in Safari. It will probably be part of the next release though. It's already available if you switch on the "Modern WebAudio API".

For now you would need to use a polyfill. [standardized-audio-context](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/standardized-audio-context) for example has an implementation of the StereoPannerNode which works in Safari. There is also the [stereo-panner-node](https://github.com/mohayonao/stereo-panner-node) package which is a standalone polyfill. But that is not maintained any longer.

Here is a little example which uses standardized-audio-context:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <audio crossOrigin="anonymous" src="https://mp3l.jamendo.com/?trackid=1630628&format=mp31&from=app-devsite"></audio>
        <button id="play">play</button>
        <button disabled id="stop">stop</button>
        <input id="left" type="radio" name="panning" value="left"><label for="left">left</label>
        <input id="center" type="radio" name="panning" value="center" checked><label for="center">center</label>
        <input id="right" type="radio" name="panning" value="right"><label for="right">right</label>
        <script type="module">
            import { AudioContext } from 'https://jspm.dev/standardized-audio-context';

            const audioContext = new AudioContext();
            const stereoPanner = audioContext.createStereoPanner();

            const audioElement = document.querySelector('audio');
            const playButton = document.getElementById('play');
            const stopButton = document.getElementById('stop');
            const leftInput = document.getElementById('left');
            const centerInput = document.getElementById('center');
            const rightInput = document.getElementById('right');

            const mediaElementAudioSourceNode = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);

            mediaElementAudioSourceNode
                .connect(stereoPanner)
                .connect(audioContext.destination);

            playButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                stereoPanner.pan.value = leftInput.checked
                    ? -1
                    : centerInput.checked
                        ? 0
                        : 1;

                audioContext.resume();
                audioElement.play();

                playButton.disabled = true;
                stopButton.disabled = false;

                leftInput.disabled = true;
                centerInput.disabled = true;
                rightInput.disabled = true;
            });

            stopButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                audioElement.pause();
                audioElement.currentTime = 0;

                playButton.disabled = false;
                stopButton.disabled = true;

                leftInput.disabled = false;
                centerInput.disabled = false;
                rightInput.disabled = false;
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know that stereo panner is not available on safari but it also not works on mobile chrome browser. Btw i resolved this error by taking the whole code of adding sounds to panner in a function and call the function when the web page loads fully.
It is kind of weird though that i cannot do the same thing directly. Any guesses why it happens this way????? 
Also till when do you think createstereopanner will be available on safari because it is troublesome to create a whole other function only for safari. Did the developers inform about it??

Comment: If that mobile Chrome browser you are referring to is running on iOS then it's not a "real" Chrome browser. At least it doesn't use Chromium. Apple forces any browser to use Webkit which means on iOS any browser is more or less a Safari with a different skin and will not have a StereoPannerNode. I have no idea when the next version of Safari will be released and if it will have the StereoPannerNode or not. Apple does not make any public comment on that.

Comment: No I am talking about chrome browser on android. Also if you can explain or give some code demo on how to convert my panner audio function above to work on apple with **standardized-audio-context** as you stated. I have absolutely no idea on it and I cannot understand much from the links you gave.

Comment: That's weird that Chrome on Android doesn't have a StereoPanner. Could that maybe be another error? I've added an example which uses standardized-audio-context. I hope that helps.

Comment: Will the code work on all devices including safari??
If yes then how can I add a function to execute this code only on apple devices. 

[The code I added above in question was not working on android. So I added the whole code in a function and call the function after the page loads. <-- if anyone wants the solution to my question]

Comment: It should work in all browsers that standardized-audio-context supports. Currently that's Chrome v81+, Edge v81+, Firefox v70+, Opera v68+ and Safari v12.1+. It's hard to know if that really was the reason why your code didn't work on Android but maybe it ran too soon and `document.querySelector` did not return any results since the DOM wasn't build yet. In that case it would make sense that it works now when running the code in response to the page load.

Comment: Hey chris one more thing, as i see in your code there is not much difference than mine one. The only major change which I see in it is `import { AudioContext } from 
'https://jspm.dev/standardized-audio-context';` 
Does this mean I have to add only this line before audio context is initialized and my code will work across all browsers or is there some other catch also.

Comment: Yes that should be all. At least unless you use another constructor from the Web Audio API. If you replace `audioContext.createStereoPanner()` with `new StereoPannerNode(audioContext)` the `StereoPannerNode` would have to be imported as well. You could also use a bundler like webpack to bundle standardized-audio-context with your code.